# Turn fonts size proportional to iframe size

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I'm trying to create an iframe to simulate an iphone screen but i'm having problems to make font size be proportional to iframe size ( height x width ). I've put 320x480 just for tests.

Anyone have an idea how can i do this trick?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function makeIframe() {
            var content = "<!DOCTYPE html><html lang='en'><head><meta name=" +  
                + "'viewport' content='width=320, height=480, initial-scale=0.5,"
                     + "maximum-scale=0.5," + 
                " minimum-scale=0.5, user-scalable=no' /></head><body>" +
                "<h1>Test</h1></body></html>";
            alert('content >> ' + content);  
            var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
            // iphone 4
            iframe.height = 480;
            iframe.width = 320;         
            document.body.appendChild(iframe);
            iframe.contentWindow.document.open('text/htmlreplace');
            iframe.contentWindow.document.write(content);
            iframe.contentWindow.document.close();
            alert('2'); 
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="body"></div>
    <input type="button" onclick="makeIframe()" value="Make" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: take out everything but the width and height in your viewport tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could try to use em in your body tag:

```
<body style='font-size: 0.2em'>
```

then all the font-size inside body tag would be small.

JS Fiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/nq0hdxae/